Calculating attributes of partially overlapping lines (roads, speeds) in QGIS
I have traffic speed data for a city covering 24 hours, represented as 24-line shapefiles. I want to calculate the average speed for the day, but many roads have partial overlaps.
In the provided diagram, the bright blue sections represent line data collected during the same time period. For example, the lines in Figure B are part of the lines in Figure A. When I use Python's combined_gdf.groupby to compute the average speed, these lines are recognized as two separate entities due to their incomplete overlap.
However, I want to calculate the average for the overlapping sections (For instance, if the speed attributes of the overlapping lines are 50 and 30, I would like the output to be 40). If there is no overlap, I want to use the individual value (for example, if one value is 50 and the other is "no data," the result should be 50) to obtain the daily average.
I attempted to use the "union" operation to resolve this issue, but due to the large size of the data, QGIS is unable to process it.


Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You have tags for qgis and arcgis-pro but don't describe the actual problem in either. Please [Edit] the Question to focus it on one product and the exact problem, then ask a question.
